# Debugging slow boot: soft lockup

Tags: boot, gpu

Recently my boot time significantly increased. The screen goes black after grub, the  monitor turns off and after a couple of minutes (it used to be <10s), the login screen appears. I use Ubuntu 22.04.

In `dmesg`, I can see:

```
watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s! [gpu-manager:879]
```

```
$ systemd-analyze blame | head
2min 51.572s gpu-manager.service
2min 17.629s docker.service
1min 42.960s plymouth-quit-wait.service
1min 42.890s postgresql@10-main.service
 1min 8.731s snapd.service
 1min 8.581s containerd.service
     34.403s avahi-daemon.service
     34.401s bluetooth.service
     34.395s NetworkManager.service
     34.386s power-profiles-daemon.service
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=6dd5bb0f-d520-4e28-9162-abbfe26b2cc6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=2082-E229  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=9e0c4e6c-7c6b-483d-af13-c87ebf7b5dd5 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I confirmed that it's the nvidia (proprietary) driver that's chosen in `Additional drivers`, added `nouveau.modeset=0` in grub, after looking online. I also checked the memory. The shutdown is also very slow.

Updating the Nvidia driver from 510 to 515, temporarily resolved it, but a couple of days later the issue is back, now with up to date drivers.

Any suggestions for how to debug this further?

Comment: Please add additional info to the question, not as a comment where it may get missed.

Comment: It looks like the comment about WiFi was premature.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the Nvidia developer forums, you can see a few issues related to soft lockups as a result of the newer drivers. https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/search?q=linux%20soft%20lockup%20%20order%3Alatest_topic

I always used to run the latest Nvidia drivers, but I kept encountering issues. I am currently using `nvidia-driver-470` which gives me the same performance as `nvidia-driver-515`, but without multi-monitor issues or soft lockups.

You can see a list of available drivers with `apt list nvidia-driver-*`

There are also the 520 drivers available here: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/193764/en-us/ but these appear to be having some of the same issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately downgrading to 470 didn't solve the issue for me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Can you confirm that the nouveau driver is blacklisted? Try `nomodeset` and `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` cmdline options.

Comment: yes, I have nouveau blacklisted.